# Name of a 6 vertices graph

Tags: graph-theory

Does this undirected graph with 6 vertices and 9 undirected edges have a name?
[image]
I know a few names that are not right. It is not a complete graph because all the vertices are not connected. It is close to K<sub>3,3</sub> the utility graph, but not quite (and not quite matters in graph theory :-)

This graph came up in my analysis of quaternion triple products.

Comment: It is the complement of $K_3\sqcup K_3$, no?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is exactly $K_{3,3}$. What makes you say it's only "close" to it? Can you spot two independent sets of 3 vertices each here? Once you see that, and given that there are 9 edges, it **must** be the complete bipartite graph on two sets of 3 vertices each.

Comment: Yup, you are right, it is $K_{3,3}$

Answer (score 8):

Take two opposing vertices (the leftmost and rightmost will do).  Now swap them and draw the resulting picture.

You should get a very clear $K_{3,3}$ as a result.

Comment: Thanks, that was the picture I needed to see.

Answer (score 2):

You can also think of it as the [Harary graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HararyGraph.html) $H_{3,6}$.